# Null pointer Exception in method getItemCount

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

I am using a list with card view and recyclerview.  I have added adapter for the list and added the getItemCount method. I want to add a search function for my list. So I have added a filter too. But when I am typing in the search view I am getting an Exception on return  ItemList.size(); this line.. What Am I missing??

Adapter

```
public class ItemAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    public ItemsFilter itemFilter;
    ArrayList<Item> mStringFilterList;
    private ArrayList<Item> ItemList;
    private Context context;
    private MyItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    private MyItemLongClickListener mItemLongClickListener;

        public ItemAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> ItemList) {
           this.context= context;
            this.ItemList = ItemList;

        }

        @Override
        public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, null);
            ListViewHolder mh = new ListViewHolder(v);

            return mh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder ListViewHolder, int i) {
            Item Item = ItemList.get(i);
            ListViewHolder.textName.setText(Item.getItem_name());
            ListViewHolder.textDesc.setText(Item.getItem_desc());
            ListViewHolder.textQty.setText(Item.getItem_qty());
            ListViewHolder.textName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return  ItemList.size();
        }
    public class ItemsFilter extends Filter {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<Item> filterList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                        if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getItem_name())
                                .contains(constraint.toString())) {

                            Item item = new Item(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                    .getItem_name(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                    .getItem_desc(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                    .getItem_qty());

                            filterList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = filterList.size();
                    results.values = filterList;
                } else {
                    results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                    results.values = mStringFilterList;
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                       Filter.FilterResults results) {
                ItemList = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // return a filter that filters data based on a constraint

        if (itemFilter == null) {
            itemFilter = new ItemsFilter();
        }
        return itemFilter;
    }
}
```

fragment

```
public class ViewStock extends Fragment  implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    final MainActivity act = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();


    public ViewStock() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_stock, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        act.array_data = new ArrayList<Item>();
        //   act.listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
       // act. = new ArrayList<Item>();
        // Context mCtx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        //   ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, act.arrayList);
        // listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        act.db = new DBHandler(getActivity());
        ArrayList<Item> item_array_from_db = act.db.Get_items();

        for (int i = 0; i < item_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

            int idno = item_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
            String name = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_name();
            String desc = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_desc();
            String qty = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_qty();
            Item cnt = new Item();
            cnt.setID(idno);
            cnt.setItem_name(name);
            cnt.setItem_desc(desc);
            cnt.setItem_qty(qty);

            act.array_data.add(cnt);
        }
        act.db.close();
        act.adapter=new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),act.array_data);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(act.adapter);

        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            act.adapter.getFilter().filter("");
        } else {
            act.adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

class

```
public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String item_name;
    public String item_desc;
    public String item_qty;

    public Item(){}
    public Item(int id, String item_name, String item_desc, String item_qty) {
        super();
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc = item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public Item(String item_name, String item_desc, String item_qty){
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getItem_name(){
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(String item_name)
    {
        this.item_name=item_name;
    }

    public String getItem_desc()
    {
        return  item_desc;
    }
    public  void setItem_desc(String item_desc)
    {
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
    }
    public String getItem_qty()
    {
        return  item_qty;
    }
    public void setItem_qty(String item_qty) {
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just paste your code. Where is actually the `NullPointerExcepton` occurred mention it - by comment.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: I have mentioned..          return  ItemList.size(); -------This line throws exception

Comment: If it throws an exception it means that `ItemList` is null.

Are you calling the constructor `ItemAdapter` before calling `getItemCount` (and passing a non-null `ArrayList` to it)?

Comment: public ItemAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> ItemList) {
           this.context= context;
            this.ItemList = ItemList;

        }
--------------------------------------This is constructor

Answer (score 9):

`ItemList` is getting set to `null` somewhere. One way to guard against this is to change your `getItemCount` method to return 0 if the list is null:

```
int getItemCount(){
    return  ItemList == null ? 0 : ItemList.size();
}
```

Comment: I dont get any list to search from..

Comment: In act.adapter=new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),act.array_data), can you verify that act.array_data is not null.

Comment: Item cnt = new Item();
            cnt.setID(idno);
            cnt.setItem_name(name);
            cnt.setItem_desc(desc);
            cnt.setItem_qty(qty);

            act.array_data.add(cnt);--------------------- Yes As act.array_data contains the list as i can view the items in list.

Answer (score 6):

Just initialize your ItemList like,

```
  private ArrayList<Item> ItemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

1. Below method not work your app open close again and again.
2. But above method work for null pointer exception. You should initialize this on recycler view activity.java section.

OR, Add a check in your getItemCount()

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        If (ItemList == null)
           return 0;
        else
           return  ItemList.size();
    }
```

**EDITED**

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (ItemList == null)
           return 0;
        else
           return  ItemList.size();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if that is the goal here.

If you look at the constructor, you notice it takes an `ArrayList<Item>` as an argument, which he then links the `ItemList` variable to

Comment: ItemList in that Argument could be null and it could never actually initializes the ItemList in use.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

So instead of making a new `ArrayList`, OP should making sure to check if what he passes into his constructor is null, rather than just making a new empty `ArrayList` and assuming it will get written over.

Comment: @dhun --- Is the syntax right??

Comment: The `if` should be lowercase.

Comment: @dhun---- I have tried that the list is empty.

Comment: @Marcin---- Please guide me the right code.

Comment: If your `ItemList` is empty it means that the `ItemList` being passed in the `ItemAdapter` constructor is null.

Make sure the argument you are passing there is correct, and not just a `null` list.

Comment: @Marcin------ sorry dint get u. Please mentiob the code.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: @Marcin... How do i get the list in cardview if the ItemList is emmpty??? when i type in the list view the list disappears now after updating the code showm by dhun.

Comment: @dhun.... The exception is gone but i am not getting the desired result of search view. The list is blank when i enter in search.

Comment: Are you implementing the search functionality right?